# Batch Script: Select top x files in directory & transfer these files to remote server

Tags: batch-file, sftp, winscp

I've files of particular ext (.xml) in a folder and I would like to select top x files, create a variable of those files, create list of remote server path & pass them in a variable to transfer the files to remote server using a batch script.

The files follows a pattern of same name which is being repeated again-n-again after n files and the number keeps on changing. For example: Add_Service_AS779.xml, Modify_Service_MS779.xml, Delete_Service_DS779.xml, Add_Service_AS554.xml, Modify_Service_MS554.xml, Delete_Service_DS554.xml and so on.

I'm able to select the last created file in that folder and transfer the same to remote server by creating a variable as well.

Shown below is the script which I'm able to achieve so far: **upload.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /r /b /a-d /o:d "C:\sample\Test" ') do set "filename=%%a"
echo %filename%
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
  /command ^
    "open sftp://username:password@ip_address/ -hostkey=""key""" ^
    "put %filename% /test/async_messages/" ^
    "exit"
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

```
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL
set /a count=5
set "filelist="

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /r /b /a-d /o:-d "C:\sample\Test" ') do if defined count set "filename=%%a" &call :transfer
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
  /command ^
    "open sftp://username:password@ip_address/ -hostkey=""key""" ^
    "put %filelist% /test/async_messages/" ^
    "exit"

goto :eof

:transfer
echo %filename%
set "filelist=%filelist% "%filename%""
set /a count-=1
if %count%==0 set "count="
goto :eof
```

[not tested - should work]

First, add a `setlocal` command so that the environment is restored after running the batch.

then set a variable (`count`, for example) to the required number of transfers.

NOTE that the `dir` command has been altered - `/o:-d` to generate the file-list in *reverse*-date order.

If `count` is defined, execute the transfer in the routine `:transfer`. Decrement the `count` variable, and if it has now been decremented to `0`, then remove it from the environment by assigning an empty string to it.

So, once that number of files has been transferred, `count` will become undefined and the `call :transfer` will not be executed.

Note the addition of `goto :eof` which transfers execution to the end-of-batch-file, terminating the batch or routine.

I've no idea of what your transfer code is doing - it's an unfamiliar construct to me. I've no idea whether the `"exit"` is part of the normal operation of whatever the command is, or whether it's an exit-from-batch, in which case it's likely that it would need to be removed.

Comment:
Modified per suggestion by Martin Prikryl. The list built in `filelist` is a space-separated list of filenames. Since filenames may contain spaces, I have quoted those filenames as they are added, so `filelist` should contain `"filename1" "file name one" "file1"`. I don't know whether this will interfere with the `WinSCP` command. If a different character is used in place of the rabbit's ears (`"`) then substitute (or remove, if required) the inner two `"` in the `set "filelist=%filelist% "%filename%""` command.

The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty; in which case `var` becomes *undefined*) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned. In this *particular* case, it may not be required, it's just a general rule of batch.

Comment: It would more effective, if you generate a space separated file list and put it into the `put` command like `"put %filelist% /test/async_messages/"` – This way, the connection would have to be opened only once. – While in the current code, you are starting WinSCP and opening and closing the connection for each file separately.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl : As I said, I've no idea what OP's code is doing as I've never seen the `...WinSCP.com...` palaver before. You may well be right - in fact, I'll bow to your superior knowledge of that matter. You could indeed build a list of the required strings in the `transfer` routine by appending `%filename%` each time `:transfer` is executed, but I've no idea whatever how that would fit in the `...WinSCP.com...` mystery.

Comment: I understand that. You know batch files better. I know WinSCP better. Hence my suggestion. Modify the code for so that you generate space-separated list of files. And then call WinSCP only once: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^  /command ^
    "open sftp://username:password@ip_address/ -hostkey=""key""" ^
    "put file1 file2 file3 ... /test/async_messages/" ^
    "exit"`

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: Fixed - I think. Problem is, I've no idea how this facility deals with quoted filenames, or is that no-issue?

Comment: The OP's code does not deal with spaces in file names either, so I've ignored that problem for now. If you want to handle that correctly, the generated script should be like `"put ""file 1"" ""file 2"" ""file 3"" ... /test/async_messages/" ^`.

Comment: Hi everyone, I tried with the code changes provided but it didn't gave me the result I wanted instead it selected the non-required files from the directory.

Comment: Try changing the `-d` to `d`. Unfortunately, "top x"  is not particularly descriptive. "The non-required" -as written, it should have selected the OLDEST (5) files. With the change I suggest here, it should select the NEWEST files. Or does it select all BUT the required files?